# Is there a way to move a call to ASP GetLocalResourceObject to a external static/shared method?

Tags: asp.net, oop, resources

I am using local resource strings in ASP. My strings are something like `"This is a {0}"`
I am using String.Format to replace the {0} value.

In anycase, rather the put this code in every page, I wanted to create a Static/Shared method that any page could call. I had thought that I could pass the page in and call the `GetLocalResourceObject()` method. `GetLocalResourceObject()` is protected so its not valid.

Is there a way to call this external to the code-behind?

```
Shared Function GetPatternedResourceString(Byval P as Page, ByVal key As String, ByVal replacement As String) As String

        Return String.Format(p.GetLocalResourceObject(key), replacement)

    End Function
```

I realize there are some other ways to get a local resource, I think there is one on HttpContext but you need to do some extra work and pass in url paths, etc.

This is actually the same problem listed here 
[VB.NET: Extension method for pages that uses GetLocalResourceObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973771/vb-net-extension-method-for-pages-that-uses-getlocalresourceobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetLocalResourceObject()` - Gets a page-level resource object based on the specified VirtualPath and ResourceKey properties. For more clarification you should read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149952.aspx)